# Did Cassandra really suitable to store log message?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am looking for a NoSQL database to store firewall traffic log message from thousand of firewall devices. I hope the noSQL database can achieve 100% uptime with build-in multiple data center support, Cassandra seems a good choice for me.

The firewall log message i would like to store in Cassandra look like that

> date=2014-07-04 time=14:26:59 type=traffic subtype=local
>   level=notice vd=vdom1 srcip=10.6.30.254 srcport=54705 srcintf="mgmt1"
>   dstip=10.6.30.1 dstport=80 dstintf="vdom1" sessionid=350696 status=close
>   policyid=0 dstcountry="Reserved" srccountry="Reserved" trandisp=noop service=HTTP

When i tried to create a table(column families) with multiple of columns corresponding to above log message key-value pair. i found it hard to define the table primary key/composite key **because hundred of log message similar to above log example can be generated within the same second!**

In order to uniquely identify each row, the primary key probably need to include almost all the columns..... which make me feel weird.

Did Cassandra really good for storing time series log message or i should consider another NoSQL database like MongoDB? Thanks.

Regards
Ro

Comment: I would start this analysis backward. Not how you should **store** these logs, but how you want to **query** them.

Comment: Regarding @SergeyKovalev comment, you should really start understanding the basic principles of Cassandras [data model](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling), especially the part below "Model Around Your Queries"